# Cumulative OLS with Python Pandas

Tags: python, optimization, pandas, regression

I am using Pandas 0.8.1, and at the moment I can't change the version. If a newer version will help the problem below, please note it in a comment rather than an answer. Also, this is for a research replication project, so even though re-running a regression after appending only one new data point might be silly (if the data set is large), I still have to do it. Thanks!

In Pandas, there is a `rolling` option for the `window_type` argument to `pandas.ols` but it seems implicit that this requires some choice of a window size or use of the whole data sample as default. I'm looking to instead use all the data in a cumulative fashion.

I am trying to run a regression on a `pandas.DataFrame` that is sorted by date. For each index `i`, I want to run a regression using the data available from the minimum date up through the date at index `i`. So the window effectively grows by one on every iteration, all data is cumulatively used from the earliest observation, and no data is ever dropped out of the window.

I have written a function (below) that works with `apply` to perform this, but it is unacceptably slow. Instead, is there a way to use `pandas.ols` to directly perform this sort of cumulative regression?

Here are some more specifics about my data. I have a `pandas.DataFrame` containing a column of identifier, a column of dates, a column of left-hand-side values, and a column of right-hand-side values. I want to use `groupby` to group based on the identifier, and then perform a cumulative regression for every time period consisting of the left-hand and right-hand-side variables.

Here is the function I am able to use with `apply` on the identifier-grouped object:

```
def cumulative_ols(
                   data_frame, 
                   lhs_column, 
                   rhs_column, 
                   date_column,
                   min_obs=60
                  ):

    beta_dict = {}
    for dt in data_frame[date_column].unique():
        cur_df = data_frame[data_frame[date_column] <= dt]
        obs_count = cur_df[lhs_column].notnull().sum()

        if min_obs <= obs_count:
            beta = pandas.ols(
                              y=cur_df[lhs_column],
                              x=cur_df[rhs_column],
                             ).beta.ix['x']
            ###
        else:
            beta = np.NaN
        ###
        beta_dict[dt] = beta
    ###

    beta_df = pandas.DataFrame(pandas.Series(beta_dict, name="FactorBeta"))
    beta_df.index.name = date_column
    return beta_df
```

Comment: have you had a look at `pd.expanding_apply()`?

Comment: That appears to be in a newer version, but I'll definitely take a look. Thanks!

Comment: @EMS in case you cannot upgrade, expanding_apply is really just syntactic sugar. if you specify rolling_apply with the window size being the length of the entire set and min_periods equal to 1, then you get the same expanding window behavior

Comment: pandas does offer cumsum (cumulative sum) and cumprod (cumulative product) that you could apply to a series. If you can break down you reduce your function into products and sums you could achieve what you are trying to do...

Comment: Yes, I actually spent most of last evening doing just this. I will post the function that I created for the univariate regression coefficient. It is unbelievable how much faster this makes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on the advice in the comments, I created my own function that can be used with `apply` and which relies on `cumsum` to accumulate all the individual needed terms for expressing the coefficient from an OLS univariate regression vectorially.

```
def cumulative_ols(
    data_frame,
    lhs_column,
    rhs_column,
    date_column,
    min_obs=60,
):
    """
    Function to perform a cumulative OLS on a Pandas data frame. It is
    meant to be used with `apply` after grouping the data frame by categories
    and sorting by date, so that the regression below applies to the time
    series of a single category's data and the use of `cumsum` will work    
    appropriately given sorted dates. It is also assumed that the date 
    conventions of the left-hand-side and right-hand-side variables have been 
    arranged by the user to match up with any lagging conventions needed.

    This OLS is implicitly univariate and relies on the simplification to the
    formula:

    Cov(x,y) ~ (1/n)*sum(x*y) - (1/n)*sum(x)*(1/n)*sum(y)
    Var(x)   ~ (1/n)*sum(x^2) - ((1/n)*sum(x))^2
    beta     ~ Cov(x,y) / Var(x)
    
    and the code makes a further simplification be cancelling one factor 
    of (1/n).

    Notes: one easy improvement is to change the date column to a generic sort
    column since there's no special reason the regressions need to be time-
    series specific.
    """
    data_frame["xy"]         = (data_frame[lhs_column] * data_frame[rhs_column]).fillna(0.0)
    data_frame["x2"]         = (data_frame[rhs_column]**2).fillna(0.0)
    data_frame["yobs"]       = data_frame[lhs_column].notnull().map(int)
    data_frame["xobs"]       = data_frame[rhs_column].notnull().map(int)
    data_frame["cum_yobs"]   = data_frame["yobs"].cumsum()
    data_frame["cum_xobs"]   = data_frame["xobs"].cumsum()
    data_frame["cumsum_xy"]  = data_frame["xy"].cumsum()
    data_frame["cumsum_x2"]  = data_frame["x2"].cumsum()
    data_frame["cumsum_x"]   = data_frame[rhs_column].fillna(0.0).cumsum()
    data_frame["cumsum_y"]   = data_frame[lhs_column].fillna(0.0).cumsum()
    data_frame["cum_cov"]    = data_frame["cumsum_xy"] - (1.0/data_frame["cum_yobs"])*data_frame["cumsum_x"]*data_frame["cumsum_y"]
    data_frame["cum_x_var"]  = data_frame["cumsum_x2"] - (1.0/data_frame["cum_xobs"])*(data_frame["cumsum_x"])**2
    data_frame["FactorBeta"] = data_frame["cum_cov"]/data_frame["cum_x_var"]
    data_frame["FactorBeta"][data_frame["cum_yobs"] < min_obs] = np.NaN
    return data_frame[[date_column, "FactorBeta"]].set_index(date_column)
### End cumulative_ols
```

I have verified on numerous test cases that this matches the output of my former function and the output of NumPy's `linalg.lstsq` function. I haven't done a full benchmark on the timing, but anecdotally, it is around 50 times faster in the cases I've been working on.